# Type void is not assignable to type ReactNode wile rendering a list of items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this piece of code, which would iterate over an object's KVPs and make a list out of them.

```
import { PersoanaType } from "./PersoanaType";

type Props = {
    persoana: PersoanaType
}

export default function PersoanaDetails(props: Props) {
    return (
        <ul>
            {
                props.persoana &&
                Object.entries(props.persoana).forEach(([key, value], index) => 
                    <li>value</li>
                )
            }
        </ul>
    );
}
```

Unfortunately, for some reason, I get this error :

```
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
```

I can't get why. So, why is this happening and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) as you want to return an array of elements here. Then make sure to add a `key` to each element in the loop, like so:

```
import { PersoanaType } from "./PersoanaType";

type Props = {
  persoana: PersoanaType;
};

export default function PersoanaDetails(props: Props) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.persoana &&
        Object.entries(props.persoana).map(([key, value], index) => <li key={key}>{value}</li>)}
    </ul>
  );
}
```